# Under what circumstances does pgrep -x fail to return a valid pid?

Tags: process, ps

I have an application running

```
$ ps -ef | grep hello_world
steve     9607  1816  0 09:11 ?        00:00:00 ./hello_world
steve    10093 21566  0 09:18 pts/4    00:00:00 grep hello_world
```

I can use `pgrep -f` to search for the pid using a pattern

```
$ pgrep -f ./hello_world
9607
$ echo $?
0

$ pgrep -f hello_world
9607
$ echo $?
0
```

However, if I use `pgrep -x` to search for an *exact* pattern match, it returns nothing

```
$ pgrep -x ./hello_world
$ echo $?
1

$ pgrep -x hello_world
$ echo $?
1
```

Checking the the `/proc` filesystem for the exact command line, it returns the following:

```
$ cat /proc/9607/cmdline
./hello_world
```

Why is `pgrep -x` failing for me?

Comment: Are you running this on Linux?  IIRC that's a long-standing bug in `procps-ng`.  On a side note, the program pattern is supposed to be an extended regular expression, not a plain string, so your `pgrep -f ./hello_world` matches by accident, rather than by design.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes this is on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 to be specific)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> $ pgrep -x ./hello_world
> $ echo $?
> 1
> ```

The reason why the first expression does not match is because you are asking `pgrep` to look for an exact process name match (with the procesess name being `hello_world` in your example), but you provide `./hello_world` as the search string.

> ```
> $ pgrep -x hello_world
> $ echo $?
> 1
> ```

Why the second search does not work for you, I have no idea. It works on Ubuntu 14.04, so either there's some kind of an error in your post, or there is a bug in the newer version:

```
$ ./dd &
[1] 6377
$ pgrep -x dd
6377
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that procps' implementation of `pgrep -x` and regex matching is broken:

```
$ /bin/sleep 9& pgrep -x 'sleep'
[1] 8472
8472
$ /bin/sleep 9& pgrep '^sleep$'
[2] 8485
8472
8485
$
```

From my reading of the man page, both of these should return null.

Consider `pidof` instead.

---

There is an annoying case where one wants to exclude a wrapper script, in this case called `sleep`:

```
#!//bin////bash
echo "Script PID: $$"
/bin/sleep 1&
pgrep -ax sleep
```

The output is:

```
Script PID: 12973                              
12973 //bin////bash ./sleep                    
12974 /bin/sleep 1
```

Comment: I see nothing strange here. The process name is `sleep`...

Comment: Compare output of `ps -o comm`, for example.

Comment: How to operate on `$0` / `ARGV[0]` then, while still allowing whitespace in paths? I've updated the answer to show why this matters.